# Flutter missing implementation for print

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm starting to learn flutter/dart, and stuck with a basic print.

I have some basic app working via Android Studio.

I note, I can use 'print' and 'debugPrint' in the myLocationApp class fine, but not in the myTestLocation class.

If I try and use the

```
print( myTestString );
```

The error is

```
compiler message: lib/main.dart:8:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'MyTestLocation' is missing implementations for these members:
compiler message:   'print'.
```

When I search online eg [here](https://flutter.io/debugging/#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs), it doesn't mention any of this, so what is the main essence I'm missing here, I'm guessing I need to amend the class to include/reference print ? But not sure what the best method would be.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

void main() => runApp(new MyLocationApp());

class MyTestLocation  {
  String myTestString = "Testing2";
  print( myTestString ); // No implentation error here

}

class MyLocationApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

```
final location = new MyTestLocation();
debugPrint( location.toString() );

return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Welcome',
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('appBarTitle'),
    ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text( location.myTestString ),
      )
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it is that you would like to print "print(myTestString)" at the time you initialize the class (line: final location = new MyTestLocation();). To achieve that you have to implement a constructor of MyTestLocation like this:

```
class MyTestLocation {
  String myTestString = "Testing2";

  MyTestLocation() {
    print(myTestString);
  }
}
```

The code you write in the root of any class has a declarative function (is not "running" as to say).

Comment: Aha yes I see now, my misunderstanding of that with classes! That works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Your class `MyTestLocation` contains an error. Basically with your following code

```
class MyTestLocation  {
  String myTestString = "Testing2";
  print( myTestString ); // No implentation error here
}
```

You defined a class `MyTestLocation` with a field `myTestString` initialized to `Testing2` and an abstract method `print` with a parameter named `myTestString`. Just remove this print line and your app should work.

**edit:** fixing the mess I made - sorry

Comment: Yes, I know there's an error there, hence the comment next to it, but I'm trying to find how I would print something from that class (ie for debugging).